# "Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged" message when presenting modal

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I have a navigation controller and root view. Then in that root view, I pushed a view there I have to click to watch the content, if logged in, if not logged it, it would open a modal view controller with the below code.

```
        var vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController
        self.tabBarController!.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

In viewdidload() i have a nsnotification so that I could get notified when user loggedinback from login modal

```
 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: ("didDismissSecondViewController:"), name: "SecondViewControllerDismissed", object: nil)
```

In Login controller after all work I wrote the below code

```
 self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("SecondViewControllerDismissed", object: nil, userInfo: nil)});
```

So in my first view controller I wrote the below code

```
func didDismissSecondViewController(sender: AnyObject)
{
    NSLog("Called ns notifications")
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{

        let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() == true {
let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc : VideoPlayViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("video") as! VideoPlayViewController
        vc.movieUrl = self.movieURL
        NSLog("URL:- \(self.movieURL)")
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)

        self.presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
        else
        {

         var alert = UIAlertView(title: "No Internet connection", message: "Please ensure you are connected to the Internet. Connect to internet and and choose any sorting option to reload.", delegate: self,  cancelButtonTitle: "Cancel")
                alert.addButtonWithTitle("Ok")
                alert.show()


        }


    })

}
```

However, when it tries to present the view controller after dismiss login controller, it shows "Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged" Error and it crashed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank God I found the answer!!!

```
var viewCon:UIViewController = self.presentingViewController!

self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

let vc : VideoPlayViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("video") as! VideoPlayViewController

vc.movieUrl = self.movieUrl

let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)

viewCon.presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)});
```

Comment: And _what_ was the answer, exactly? A block of code alone isn't very explanatory...