# View not in View Hierachy while trying to present Navigation Controller as rootViewController

Tags: ios, swift

```
@IBAction func logOut(sender: AnyObject) {
    PFUser.logOutInBackground()


    let MainView: UIViewController = self.presentingViewController!

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc: UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as UIViewController

    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)

        MainView.presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)})
}
```

I connect a `ViewController` using the **Push** segue and inside that `ViewController`i have button that log the user out, It does not push me all the way to the rootViewController instantly but get stuck in the "login" `ViewController` then pushes up the `ViewController` from the bottom then showing the error:  **Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!**

Comment: have you tried this question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31876720/presenting-view-controllers-on-detached-view-controllers-is-discouraged-when-pre

Comment: That did not work, i got this error instead: Warning: Attempt to present <Social_App.ViewController: 0x7fde9e7804b0> on <Social_App.settingAndStuffViewController: 0x7fde9e775550> whose view is not in the window hierarchy! @OXXY

Comment: Code that i tried: `let MainView: UIViewController = self.presentingViewController!
        
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc: UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as UIViewController
        
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
        
            MainView.presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)})` @OXXY

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you are trying to come back to the root view controller on logout?

You could just do.
   `self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)`

Comment: The page i want to come back to is not in the same Stack as the viewcontroller with the logout button.

Comment: Ok, but even in that case, the two stacks must be connected at some place. For eg: At the start of the stack you have a navigation controller. The error/warning that you are getting is that you are trying push an unrelated VC on to the stack.

Think of it this way, the Navigation controller is always at the bottom of the stack. The Navigation controllers pushes and pops VC that it manages. It is not correct to push an unrelated VC on the stack. 

If you want to present a VC that is not in the stack, you need to navigate back to the root of the stack. And then present the new VC.

Comment: If you could add a pictorial description of how the different VC's are connected. It would help suggest how handle the navigation.

Comment: I fixed it, check my latest answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
let vc: UIViewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as UIViewController

    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)

    self.presentViewController(navigationController, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

This does not create any error and connects the closest NavigationController to the ViewController.